# How to retrieve telemetry for all customer devices from Thingsboard via websocket

Tags: thingsboard, telemetry

I want to get the latest telemetry for all devices related to a single customer from thingsboard CE via API over a websocket.  So that I can update a jquery datatable in real-time when measurements are received.

*after* manually adding a relation for `customer->device` via GUI latest telemetry data is now flowing to the CUSTOMER entityType in Thingsboard.

However; the data returned does not contain any device attribute information that I can use to match the ws response to the device that generated the measurements.

```
{"subscriptionId":10,"errorCode":0,"errorMsg":null,"data":{"battery_voltage":[[1559065098932,"2.8623046875"]],"pressure":[[1559065098932,"0.05001525953412056"]],"relative_humidity":[[1559065098932,"53.7109375"]],"temperature":[[1559065098932,"83.78323364257812"]]},"latestValues":{"battery_voltage":1559065098932,"temperature":1559065098932,"pressure":1559065098932,"relative_humidity":1559065098932}}
```

endpoint in Thingsboard:`/api/ws/plugins/telemetry`

this code works and returns latest telemetry update, but it doesn't specify which device in the returned result.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
...
webSocket.onopen = function () {
   var object = {
       tsSubCmds: [{
           entityType: "CUSTOMER",
           entityId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000...",
                        scope: "LATEST_TELEMETRY",
                        cmdId: 10
                    }
                ],
                historyCmds: [],
                attrSubCmds: []
            };
            var data = JSON.stringify(object);
            webSocket.send(data);
            console.log("Message is sent: " + data);
            console.log("socket open: ");
        };
```

How can i enrich the telemetry timeseries data with device attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to update the rule-chain in the GUI so that a copy of the incoming DEVICE telemetry data is duplicated and saved to the related CUSTOMER entity.

Step by step:

1. login to thingsboard as a tenant administrator
2. click on the `Root Rule Chain`
3. find the `Save timeseries` node on the `Post telemetry` branch
4. drag a new `filter...script` node onto the canvas
5. connect the new script node to the output of the `Save timeseries` node on the `Post Telemetry` branch
6. edit the filter script name: -> `Should Duplicate`
7. edit the filter script function -> `return true;`
8. drag a new `Transformation...change originator` node to the canvas
9. connect the new transformation node to the output of the filter node
10. edit the Transformation node name: `Reassign to Customer`
11. edit the originator source: `Customer`
12. drag a new `Action...save timeseries` node onto the canvas
13. Connect the new Action node to the output of the Transformation node
14. edit the Action node name:`Save Related Telemetry`

Your root rule chain should now look similar to this:

[image]