# Propagate telemetry from the device to the corresponding asset in Thingsboard

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard, telemetry

I have a thingsboard device to which up to 3 temperature sensors are connected via SPI. Each sensor monitors the temperature of one refrigerator (asset).

The device SPI port to which the different asset sensor is connected doesn't change with time, e.g. port_1 -> Fridge 22, port_2-> Fridge 23, port_3 -> Fridge 44.

I need to propagate the telemetry from the device to the corresponding asset. **Note that each device is related to up to 3 assets**.

It is easy if one device is related to only one asset, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226175/push-telemetry-to-thingsboard-asset), but I don't know in this case.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating 3 relation types for your device:

[image]

Just replace Test Assets with your refrigerators.

Now go to your device rulechain and add those nodes:
[image]

Lets suppose that you are posting this telemetry data from your device to thingsboard:

```
{
   "asset1_temp":1,
   "asset2_temp":2,
   "asset3_temp":3
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried and it works well, all of 3 assets have received the telemetry:

Test Asset 1: `{"temperature":1}`

Test Asset 2: `{"temperature":2}`

Test Asset 3: `{"temperature":3}`